# Manage clearence trough schematic in Altium Designer

Tags: schematics, altium

I have a multilevel project to measure different potentials and current. This is done by opto isolated amplifier. The design is similar to the image:
[image]

The sheet is reused in upper sheets multiple times.

Question: How can I add clearance rule to the schematic that describe the minimum distance between these component (the connector and only some part of the sheet entry) and the rest of my board?

EDIT:
LabPSIsoInput scheet entry hold an isolation amplifier schematic, so one half of it is on the high voltage side, the other one is on the isolated output.

What I want is to declare clearance rule (at least net class) to the mentioned part of the isolated amplfier, apply this net class to corresponding sheet entry on the image.

I want to do it so that this sheet is generated multiple times by REPEAT() macro on its parent sheet

Comment: What do you mean by "only some part of the sheet entry"? A sheet entry isn't a piece of copper, you can't really divide it into parts.

Comment: You can create classes for the different component types, then create class rules.